# Button Transition Effect using class not working accordingly

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I would like to get these [3 events](https://codepen.io/dhavaljardosh/pen/vWKgoX?editors=1100) triggered on form fill. But all are supposed to be on the same button.

Am able to achieve it using 3 classes i.e.

- "draw dj" which is first event
- "draw1 dj" which is 2nd event
- "draw2 dj" is the final event

[**This**](https://codepen.io/dhavaljardosh/pen/bYpOWx) is the form I want to edit.

### My Approach

If user completes the edit of 1st field, Event 1 is triggered as classes "draw dj" is added

then when user completes the edit of 2nd field, classes "draw dj" is replaced by "draw1 dj"(This works completely fine)

But when third event is triggered, the transition is not happening instead it converts directly to the final look.

### CSS of what I am supposed to get

```
.draw2 {
    // transition: color 0.25s;
  color: lightgrey; 
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(255,123,0),rgb(255,123,0));
  background-position: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 0% 100%;
  transition: background-size 0.5s 0.8s, color 1s 0.5s;
  &:hover{
    color:white;
    background-size:100% 100%;
  }
  &::before,
  &::after {
    // Set border to invisible, so we don't see a 4px border on a 0x0 element before the transition starts
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }

  // This covers the top & right borders (expands right, then down)
  &::before {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

  // And this the bottom & left borders (expands left, then up)
  &::after {
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
  }



  // Hover styles
  &:hover::before,
  &:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  &:hover::before {
    border-left-color: rgb(255,123,0); // Make borders visible
    border-bottom-color: rgb(255,123,0);
    transition:
      width 0s ease-out, // Width expands first
      height 0s ease-out; // And then height
  }

  &:hover::after {
    border-right-color: rgb(255,123,0); // Make borders visible
    border-top-color: rgb(255,123,0);
    color:white;
    transition:
      border-color 0s ease-out, // Wait for ::before to finish before showing border
      height 0.25s ease-out, // And then exanding width
      width 0.25s ease-out 0.25s; // And finally height
  }
}
```

---

### CSS of what I am getting right now

```
.draw2 {
    // transition: color 0.25s;
  color: lightgrey; 
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(255,123,0),rgb(255,123,0));
  background-position: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 0% 100%;
  transition: background-size 0.5s 0.8s, color 1s 0.5s;
  &.dj{
    color:white;
    background-size:100% 100%;
  }
  &::before,
  &::after {
    // Set border to invisible, so we don't see a 4px border on a 0x0 element before the transition starts
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }

  // This covers the top & right borders (expands right, then down)
  &::before {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

  // And this the bottom & left borders (expands left, then up)
  &::after {
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
  }



  // Hover styles
  &.dj::before,
  &.dj::after {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  &.dj::before {
    border-left-color: rgb(255,123,0); // Make borders visible
    border-bottom-color: rgb(255,123,0);
    transition:
      width 0s ease-out, // Width expands first
      height 0s ease-out; // And then height
  }

  &.dj::after {
    border-right-color: rgb(255,123,0); // Make borders visible
    border-top-color: rgb(255,123,0);
    color:white;
    transition:
      border-color 0s ease-out, // Wait for ::before to finish before showing border
      height 0.25s ease-out, // And then exanding width
      width 0.25s ease-out 0.25s; // And finally height
  }
}
```

Comment: that pen does not seem to replicate your problem ( not adding any class) .

Comment: When I try to add class instead of hover, that's when it's causing problem. In  the pen I mentioned in first line.

Comment: I don't see any `:hover` styles. Your css comments have a hover section but  all you're doing is creating pseudo elements. Where is the hover animation?

Comment: Hover is just an example, i.e how I am able to achieve what I want. But I have added the same properties to my class i.e. draw2 it's in [here](https://codepen.io/dhavaljardosh/pen/bYpOWx?editors=1010). My question is bit confusing I guess, I will change it to more understandable format very soon.

Comment: and on what event does that class `draw2` appear ? on which event you change between classes ?

Comment: My purpose is to join these [**3 events**](https://codepen.io/dhavaljardosh/pen/vWKgoX) on form fill. So for that purpose I am using classes and changing the classes to serve the purpose. But there is no transition effect in the last event.

Comment: Please check my edit, @MihaiT

Comment: Please check my edit, @SergChernata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you updated the post, the last thing you're missing is the `background-size` attribute in `draw1` class.

```
.draw1 {
    background-size: 0% 100%;
    &::before,
    ...
```

CSS animations need a starting point. You were applying a class with the end value of background size but CSS had no starting point to begin the animation with. Thus, you were getting a "toggle" straight to final value.

Comment: That's working pretty good, can you please also guide me why is the border not transiting, as it just fills the background and the border is not moving and completing the loop